# Rails: class methods helpers from Lib

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry the title may not be very clear. Basically I have a wrapper for the Split gem called ABFeature in lib/ab_feature/ab_feature.rb

In my view I want to be able to call my helpers like this:

```
ABFeature.current_settings
```

But this is not working, here is the error I have:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for ABFeature:Module
```

session is a method from ActionController and is seems I can't access it...

Here is my code:

```
require 'split'

module ABFeature
  class << self
    include Split::Helper

    def current_settings
      ...
    end
  end
end


class ActionController::Base
  ActionController::Base.send :extend, ABFeature
end
```

Any idea?,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the result should be but if you want the current_settings method available in the controller I think you can do

```
module ABFeature
  include Split::Helper

  def current_settings
  end
end
```

and then

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ABFeature
end
```

I think you usually call helpers as instance methods. Then they should share the context with the controller.